# package or stack wiki for ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any guideline about how to create 3rd party package or stack wiki for ROS2?
For ROS1, contributors are free to create such wiki pages under http://wiki.ros.org (e.g. [RealSense](http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense) ), but not sure how ROS2 will manage this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281012/package-or-stack-wiki-for-ros2/) by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment there is no similar infrastructure to wiki.ros.org for ROS 2. The [ROS 2 wiki](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki) provides some information but lacks the convenience of the wiki macros like `PackageHeader`.

The ROS 1 wiki is based on MoinMoin and has exceeded the recommended maximum number of pages a long time ago. That is why we don't want to start adding ROS 2 specific information into it.

In the long term the goal is to have a similar infrastructure as for ROS 1 but currently the work towards that hasn't been started yet.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on 2018-01-29**:
Thanks, Thomas. Since I'm working on ROS2 packages (e.g. RealSense I mentioned above) and I'd like to create ROS2 wiki page for such package or stack, what's your recommendation so far? May I create a new wiki page under [ROS 2 wiki](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki) directly?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-01-29**:
That sounds fine with me.

**Comment by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on 2018-01-29**:
Thank you for your answer, Thomas!